# httpClient post call failing from a servlet with error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:

Tags: java, servlets, post, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

i am trying to make an http post call from a servlet using apache http-components client library,  stuck with the following error.

**java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity.(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/http/entity/ContentType;)V   at org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity.(UrlEncodedFormEntity.java:77)**

At the point where i am trying to create UrlEncodedEntity Object in the code

I looked up the other post and they say, its mostly because of the build path discrepancies, i have all the libs of http-components placed inside WEB_INF/lib(i am hoping this is correct) Version of the libs is 4.4. Here is the code which i wrote.

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    PrintWriter out =response.getWriter();
    out.println("Hit");
    String serviceUrl = request.getParameter("url");
    String data = request.getParameter("data");
    String type = request.getParameter("type");
    String dataType = request.getParameter("dataType");

    if(null != serviceUrl && !serviceUrl.trim().equals("")) {   

            if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("POST")){
                try {
                    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://10.53.204.233:6504/app/service/"+serviceUrl);
                    try {

                      List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                      nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type",type ));
                      nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dataType",dataType ));
                      nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data",data ));
                      UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, Consts.UTF_8);
                      post.setEntity(entity);


                      HttpResponse responseTeamServer = client.execute(post);
                      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(responseTeamServer.getEntity().getContent()));
                      String line = "";
                      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                      while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                          sb.append(line);
                      }

                      response.getWriter().write(sb.toString());
                      response.getWriter().flush();
                      response.getWriter().close();


                    }
                    catch (IOException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } finally {

                }
            }
            else{

            }
        }

    else {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
    }

}
```

Any Help or direction in this regard is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I have a similar problem. Did you solve this?

Comment: @Dan i think the problem was the multiple version of libraries in the class path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code compiled ? And you had this problem at runtime? In which case you have mutiple versions of the library within your classpath.

Seeing that the StringEntity class has been inducted from version 4 onwards, it is possible that the server/lib has an earlier version of the library that is loaded.

One way to debug this is to add 
java -verbose:class  to your server startup script. It will output class information that includes the path (jar) file from where the class was loaded. Be warned that the it does print out this for every class that is loaded which may be voluminous data to sift through.

Comment: yes the code compiles and this error is at runtime. Thanks for the tip for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

As javadoc says this constructor accept a string as second parameter, not a Charset object

Comment: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/entity/UrlEncodedFormEntity.html,

Comment: the document contains the constructor with the charset